# Approximating an unknown probability with a Gaussian and then combining these probabilites?

Tags: probability, statistics, gaussian-integral

I have a candidate C with unknown features $F = [F_1, F_2, … , F_n]$

where $F_i$ is the probability that the candidate has the feature
, unfortunately this is poorly know and must be approximated so that
 $F_i$ ~ $N(\mu_{fi},\sigma_{fi}^2)$

I appreciate that this is not bounded between 0 and 1 but the Gaussian approximation is useful for improving the estimate as more data is gathered.

There is also a user with likes $[U_1, U_2, …, U_n]$, again this is approximated $U_i$ ~ $N(\mu_{ui},\sigma_{ui}^2)$

Hence the probability that the candidate will have at least one feature that the user likes is the 1 minus the probability that the venue has no features that the user likes. This is calculated from the product of the probabilities that not(has feature and user likes feature) for each feature:
$$P(C) = 1 - P(\bar C) = 1 - \Pi (1- F_i  U_i ) $$

I believe that the mean of this distribution is:
$$\mu_c = 1 - \Pi(1- \mu_{fi} \mu_{ui}))$$

And I have been able to confirm through simulation that the distribution is a gaussian (or very well approximated by gaussian), but what's it's variance?
Any help would be much appreciated, I'm worried I may have to perform a tricky integral and have no idea how, n is roughly 370 so ideally I'm looking for a format which scales in a programable way. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can simulate the desired distribution satisfactorily, then you can find the variance of the vector of simulated values as an approximation of the variance of the distribution. // If the features are _uncorrelated_ and you know the variance of each, you might be able to combine the individual variances to get the variance of the overall dist'n. // I say _might_ because I do not fully understand how you combine 'features' to get the overall distribution.

Comment: yes the features are uncorrelated, the combining rule is the product given in my original post, and I can't simulate the distribution to the required degree of accuracy in real time. This is why I'm hoping to calculate the mean and variance from the other known means and variances.

Comment: I'm on my way to a solution:
one key mistake I made was assuming the output of multiplying gaussian variables would be a gaussian, While it is true that multiplying pdfs produces a gaussian pdf (due to it actually being a convolution)  this is not the case for variables. when multiplying two gaussians the result is actually a modified Bessel function of the second kind [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html) this looks like a normal when mu is not close to zero (the conditions are more advanced than that but it explains my mistake in this case)

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to my issue - the product of two gaussians is not a Gaussian as mentioned before, but the result can be approximated as a Gaussian with $mu = \mu_1*\mu_2$  and $\sigma^2 = \sigma_1^2 *\sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2*\mu_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 * \mu_2^2$
This is the result from this [paper](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-doi-10_7151_dmps_1146/c/dmps.1146.pdf) also referenced on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293955/normal-approximation-to-the-pointwise-hadamard-schur-product-of-two-multivariate).
This approximation gets better as either $\mu_i/\sigma_i $ gets large, but is surprisingly good as long as either $\mu_i$ is non zero (anecdotally)

If the true distribution is needed then the output can be found by looking at the [Normal Product Distrubution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html).